# React- get Data from JSON server and Display inside of a Card

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

> I'm trying to create a simple blogging website using json server(get,post,delete). In Home page the Body component will show each blog post title, image and few lines of the post ,onClick full post will be showed. It will be similar to this picture.
>
> > I'm using Material Design for Bootstrap 5 & 4 from there i found this component but from posts.map function it's not working.
> > This is what i want to achieve-

[image]

> > This is the output of my code-

[image]

> > This is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  MDBRow, MDBCol,MDBCard, MDBCardBody, MDBMask, MDBIcon, MDBView, MDBBtn,
} from 'mdbreact';
import axios from 'axios';


const Body = () => {
  const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);

  const loadData = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/post');
    setPost(result.data);
  };

  return (
    <MDBCard className='my-5 px-5 pb-5'>
      <MDBCardBody>
        <h2 className='h1-responsive font-weight-bold text-center my-5'>
          Recent posts
        </h2>

> /// map from json server to show the data inside of MDBRow component ///

        {posts.map((post, index) => {
          <MDBRow>
            <MDBCol lg='5' xl='4'>
              <MDBView hover className='rounded z-depth-1-half mb-lg-0 mb-4'>
                <img
                  className='img-fluid'
                  src='https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/49.jpg'
                  alt=''
                />
                <a href='#!'>
                  <MDBMask overlay='white-slight' />
                </a>
              </MDBView>
            </MDBCol>
            <MDBCol lg='7' xl='8'>
              <h3 className='font-weight-bold mb-3 p-0'>
                <strong>{post.title}</strong>
              </h3>
              <p className='dark-grey-text'>{post.body}</p>
              <p>
                by{' '}
                <a href='#!' className='font-weight-bold'>
                  Jessica Clark
                </a>
                , 19/04/2018
                <MDBBtn tag='a'>
                  <i
                    class='fas fa-edit'
                    size='lg'
                    style={{ color: 'blue' }}></i>
                </MDBBtn>
                <MDBBtn tag='a'>
                  <i
                    class='fas fa-trash-alt'
                    size='lg'
                    style={{ color: 'red' }}></i>
                </MDBBtn>
              </p>
              <MDBBtn color='primary' size='md'>
                Read More
              </MDBBtn>
              <MDBBtn color='danger' size='sm'>
                Delete
              </MDBBtn>
            </MDBCol>
          </MDBRow>;
        })}
        <hr className='my-5' />
      </MDBCardBody>
    </MDBCard>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think the issue come from your json file used in json server because your code works fine [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-sun-7c3b0).
Can you share your json from json server ?
By the way I removed some issues like missing key and "div can not be a descendant of p"

Comment: @antoineso I found the error. It's not in the json file , It's in the map function ! My code--- ``` {posts.map((post, index) => {} ``` , after arrow I used curly brackets which is wrong , I had to use round bracket. While checking your solution on codeSandBox i found that only difference is bracket so i tried with round bracket instead of curly one and It's working fine..  
Thanks a lot , I was trying for hours to solve this error!